# TypeError: connection.query is not a function - Issue when passing connection to another .js file

Tags: mysql, node.js, ejs

I've been developing a forum based application for a lab I'm creating however, I keep getting the following error when authenticating to the application (which uses. my authRoutes.js file):

```
TypeError: connection.query is not a function
    at /home/user/Apps/forum-app/routes/authRoutes.js:52:14
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/ellis/CCT-Apps/forum-xxs-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/user/Apps/forum-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/user/Apps/forum-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (//home/user/Apps/forum-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/user/Apps/forum-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:15
    at Function.process_params (/home/user/Apps/forum-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:346:12)
    at next (/home/user/Apps/forum-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:10)
    at Function.handle (/home/user/Apps/forum-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:175:3)
    at router (/home/user/Apps/forum-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
```

After doing some research, I assumed it was to do with the database connection not being passed from my server.js file to the authRoutes.js file properly, server.js below:

```
// server.js
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3003;
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const saltRounds = 10;
const session = require('express-session');

// MySQL database connection
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: 'xxxxx',
  database: 'xxxxx'
});

connection.connect((err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Error connecting to MySQL:', err);
    return;
  }
  console.log('Connected to MySQL');
});


// Set up session middleware
app.use(session({
  secret: 'xxxxx',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));

// Set up middleware
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.json());

// Set up EJS as view engine and specify views directory
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

// Define routes
const forumRoutes = require('./routes/forumRoutes');
const authRoutes = require('./routes/authRoutes');

// Pass the connection object to routes
app.use('/', forumRoutes);
app.use('/auth', authRoutes); // Authentication routes

// Start the server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});

module.exports = connection; // Export the connection object
console.log(connection);
```

However I can view the connection in the console log and see the query parameter is exported. However, when I view the routes/authRoutes.js file (below), I pass the imported connection to the console log and get no response.

```
// routes/authRoutes.js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const saltRounds = 10; // Number of salt rounds for bcrypt
const connection = require('../server'); // Import connection object from server.js

console.log(connection);


// GET route for rendering the login form
router.get('/login', (req, res) => {
  res.render('login'); // Assuming a login.ejs file in views directory
});

// GET route for rendering the registration form
router.get('/register', (req, res) => {
  res.render('register'); // Assuming a register.ejs file in views directory
});

// Register route
router.post('/register', (req, res) => {
  const { username, password, secretKey } = req.body;

  // Hash the password
  bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds, (err, hashedPassword) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error hashing password:', err);
      res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
      return;
    }

    // Store the user details in the database
    const newUser = { username, password: hashedPassword, secretKey };
    connection.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?', newUser, (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error('Error registering user:', err);
        res.status(500).send('Error registering user');
        return;
      }
      res.status(200).send('User registered successfully');
    });
  });
});

// Login route
router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;

  // Retrieve the user from the database by username
  const query = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?';
  connection.query(query, [username], (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error('Error retrieving user:', error);
      res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
      return;
    }

    if (results.length === 0) {
      // User with the provided username does not exist
      res.status(404).send('User not found');
      return;
    }

    const user = results[0];

    // Compare the hashed password with the provided password
    bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error('Error comparing passwords:', err);
        res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
        return;
      }

      if (!result) {
        // Passwords do not match
        res.status(401).send('Incorrect password');
        return;
      }

      // Passwords match, user authenticated successfully
      // Store user information in session
      req.session.user = {
        id: user.id,
        username: user.username
      };
      
      // Redirect to the forum post page after login
      res.redirect('/forum');
    });
  });
});

// Logout route
router.post('/logout', (req, res) => {
  // Destroy the user's session
  req.session.destroy((err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error destroying session:', err);
      res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
      return;
    }
    // Redirect the user to the login page
    res.redirect('/auth/login');
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

My assumption is the MySQL connection from server.js is not being passed properly to routes/authRoutes.js however, I checked the syntax and how its been exported and can't work out why there's an issue.

As some extra info, here is the output of running `node --trace-warnings server.js`:

```
(node:6294) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'Symbol(nodejs.util.inspect.custom)' of module exports inside circular dependency
    at emitCircularRequireWarning (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:887:11)
    at Object.get (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:903:5)
    at formatValue (node:internal/util/inspect:794:30)
    at inspect (node:internal/util/inspect:364:10)
    at formatWithOptionsInternal (node:internal/util/inspect:2298:40)
    at formatWithOptions (node:internal/util/inspect:2160:10)
    at console.value (node:internal/console/constructor:342:14)
    at console.log (node:internal/console/constructor:379:61)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/user/Apps/forum-app/routes/authRoutes.js:8:9)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
(node:6294) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'constructor' of module exports inside circular dependency
    at emitCircularRequireWarning (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:887:11)
    at Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:911:5)
    at getOwnPropertyDescriptor (<anonymous>)
    at getConstructorName (node:internal/util/inspect:591:24)
    at formatRaw (node:internal/util/inspect:850:23)
    at formatValue (node:internal/util/inspect:840:10)
    at inspect (node:internal/util/inspect:364:10)
    at formatWithOptionsInternal (node:internal/util/inspect:2298:40)
    at formatWithOptions (node:internal/util/inspect:2160:10)
    at console.value (node:internal/console/constructor:342:14)
(node:6294) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag)' of module exports inside circular dependency
    at emitCircularRequireWarning (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:887:11)
    at Object.get (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:903:5)
    at formatRaw (node:internal/util/inspect:856:18)
    at formatValue (node:internal/util/inspect:840:10)
    at inspect (node:internal/util/inspect:364:10)
    at formatWithOptionsInternal (node:internal/util/inspect:2298:40)
    at formatWithOptions (node:internal/util/inspect:2160:10)
    at console.value (node:internal/console/constructor:342:14)
    at console.log (node:internal/console/constructor:379:61)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/user/Apps/forum-app/routes/authRoutes.js:8:9)
```

I've reconfigured how its been exported multiple times however the current method I have seems to be what should be used. I've restarted the server, ran `npm install mysql` within the project folder, but no luck.